# Using UINavigationController and a tab bar together

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I added a tab bar to my UINavigation based app and the code in 'applicationWillTerminate' (see below) no longer works.  I've tried to alter the code to accommodate the tab bar but have been unable to get it to work.

How can I change the code in 'applicationWillTerminate' to work with my tab bar?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [self createTabBar];

    // this subview causes the code in 'applicationWillTerminate' to no longer work
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    RootViewController *viewController = (RootViewController *)[navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [viewController.dataOjects saveData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `[self createTabBar]` exactly do? If you create your RootViewController there programmatically you might as well just create a `@property (nonatomic, retain) RootViewController *myRootController;` in your application delegate class, save the created controller whereever it is being created (worst case: the RootViewController saves itself to the app delegate after creation in `viewDidLoad`) and just use `self.myRootController` instead of going through the view hierarchy.

This way you are independent of the actual composition of views which could even change on iOS updates if you're going through subviews of UITabbar etc.

Comment: `[self createTabBar]` is where the tab bar is setup programmatically.  The code in 'applicationWillTerminate' stopped working when I added `[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];`.  Can you please elaborate on how you think I should proceed?

Comment: In your app delegate create `@property (nonatomic retain) RootViewController *myRootController;`
then whereever you create your root view controller save it to the app delegate variable
`RootViewController *rootController = [[RootViewController alloc] init...];
    ((MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).myRootController = rootController;`

and finally use this variable in your `applicationWillTerminate`:

    `[self.myRootView.dataObjects saveData];`

thus no longer requiring to go through the view hierarchy to fetch your root view controller.

Comment: Is there a way I can change my existing code in applicationWillTerminate to accommodate the subview tabBarController? I've added the code you suggested but I'm still unable to get it to work. I also tried replacing `[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
` with `self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;` but that didn't work either. I'm really stuck on this...please help.